# Can an EU family member enter the UK using an EU residence permit?

Tags: visas, uk

I am a Sri Lankan national and passport holder, and an EU residence permit holder,  married to an EU national.

I would like to go to the UK for a short visit. Do I also need a visa to enter the UK?

Although I've looked, I haven't found a definitive answer.

Comment: **Important**: This is a pre-Brexit question, with a pre-Brexit answer, which is no longer valid.