# UK visa application requirements, family of EU citizen

Tags: ec261

I am citizen of Pakistan, and I've been living in Belgium for 4 years. I hold a permanent resident card, Family member of an EU Citizen. My husband (he is a Belgian citizen), our sons (Belgian citizens) and I would like to travel together for 7 days to the United Kingdom (Manchester).  What are the visa application requirements?

Comment: What do you want to know?

Comment: @MichaelHampton "visa application requirements"

Comment: While I voted to re-open, this may be a dupe of [Can an EU family member enter the UK using an EU residence permit?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/82813/can-an-eu-family-member-enter-the-uk-using-an-eu-residence-permit)

Answer (score 1):

There are no visa application requirements because, given the facts you describe, you do not need a visa.  See [Entering the UK as the holder of an Article 10 residence card](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card).

> If you are a non-EEA national who holds a valid genuine residence card, issued to you as the family member of an EEA national who is exercising free movement rights in another EEA State (i.e. not your EEA relative’s Member State of nationality) under Article 10 of Directive 2004/38/EC (the ‘Free Movement Directive’), you may use this document for travel to the UK if you are accompanying your EEA national relative here, or joining your EEA national relative in the UK.

You may be concerned about the qualification "not your EEA relative’s Member State of nationality," but in fact as long as your card says "family member of an EU citizen," it qualifies.